# Conda environments and .BAT files

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am setting up calls to python (Anaconda distribution) via BAT files and the windows task scheduler.

I've now used environments for the first time and was trying to set a `.bat` file up as below:

```
activate [my_env]
python my_script.py
deactivate
```

Unfortunately it appears that the second command does not get executed.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Use the 'call' command when activating/deactivating the environment.

```
call activate [my_env]
python my_script.py
call conda deactivate
```

See https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/794

Comment: Only this worked for me. And this is a proper method.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need a batch file? I think this should work.

```
cmd "/c activate [my_env] && python my_script.py && deactivate"
```

When I made a simple file containing

```
print("Hello")
```

Which I called myprint.py and ran

```
cmd "/c activate anaconda33 && python myprint.py && deactivate"
```

This worked for me. You could also put this in a one line batch file.

Comment: This did not work, but calling python in the env directory does seem to do the job like `C:\Anaconda\envs\linkdex_py27\python.exe script.python`

Comment: Have you added the anaconda binary directory to your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes, I have. I've tested the above again and noticed that it worked for me if I amended the script.py line to the fully qualified path - even though it was in the directory I started working in.

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Eliminates the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

All activate does is put the environment in the front of the PATH. You can just call the absolute path to the `python` in the environment you want, like `C:\Anaconda\python my-script.py`.

Comment: This is true, but you should be very careful about this, because activate.bat may also be putting critical DLLs on PATH also.

Comment: This even works for user-installed entry points and scripts - they will run on the environment's Python interpreter and use it's `site-packages` etc.