# Batch file not running but works when I manually type in to command line

Tags: batch-file, anaconda

Hey so I have a pretty simple request for a bat file

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\kevin\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\kevin\anaconda3
conda activate flight
python C:\Users\kevin\Documents\PythonScripts\FDIBASE.py
```

That is all I want to do. When I go into my command line manually then individually type those three lines it works perfectly fine (it does take a few seconds for each line to finish before I execute the next however)

I am new to bat files so I think its just something wrong with the format but I don't get why it does not work.

Comment: Don't use cmd.exe. Line 1) `CALL C:\path\Activate.bat` Line 2) `Call Conda activate flight` LIne 3) `Python C:\path\Fdibase.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678144/conda-environments-and-bat-files), we need using `call` to activate the conda environment

```
call C:\Users\kevin\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\kevin\anaconda3\envs\flight

python C:\Users\kevin\Documents\PythonScripts\FDIBASE.py

call conda deactivate
```