# Running .py files using spyder automatically

Tags: python, pandas, automation, spyder, windows-task-scheduler

So I created a report. I am trying to have it run daily at a specific time using task scheduler and a batch file. Almost everything is working. I can use the task scheduler to run the specific .py file I want inside of spyder. BUT I can not get it to run using pandas or any other import. I can get it to run a loop counting down from 10 as shown below. I get an error on the line 'import pandas as pd'.

```
countdown = 10

while countdown > 0:
    print ('CountDown = ', countdown)
    countdown = countdown - 1
```

^^ this works

```
import pandas as pd
```

^^ this gets the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: can you give more information and more of your code?

Comment: I don't think that would be any help to you. When I run the file in Spyder it works perfectly. The problem is when I try to run it through task scheduler with a batch file. Python 3.7 or whatever the batch file is linked to, doesn't recognize pandas or any other library that I use. I tried using !pip install pandas, but then I get a syntax error. Below is the batch file code.

Comment: "C:/Users/krushwi/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe" "C:/Users/krushwi/Desktop/Python Automation/auto_test.py"

Comment: Basically I installed Anaconda Navigator on my pc with the purpose of using spyder to write functions to automate reports. I have successfully written the functions and now I am trying to get these functions to run automatically everyday at a certain time using task scheduler and a batch file. I cannot get the batch file to properly connect to the .py fily to run automatically. Can I have help creating the batch file correctly.

Comment: I think your batch file needs to activate the conda environment where the packages you depend on are installed and then use the Python interpreter of that env to run your script/python file. Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678144/conda-environments-and-bat-files

Comment: I followed the link and added the suggestion. Can you be anymore specific? I had these errors: 
C:\WINDOWS\system32>call activate [my_env]
'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python my_script.py
python: can't open file 'my_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\WINDOWS\system32>call conda deactivate
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your help everyone. I am not sure if this is what you meant before hand but I changed my batch file to be as follows and it works to run the python script through task scheduler: pause

call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/krushwi/Desktop/Python Automation/auto_test.py"

pause